# Appending elements to a DIV from a JSON array in Polymer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

I'm struggling right now with inserting a set of divs into a core-header-panel inside a paper-shadow in Polymer. I am getting a set of values from a JSON array and I need to create a div with HTML content (eventually checkboxes) for each of the values. Here's the relevant snippet of code:

```
<paper-shadow class="card upload-options-box" z="1">
    <core-header-panel flex id="graphHeaderList">
        <core-toolbar class="upload-option-header">
            <span flex>Variable</span>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-label horizontal layout> // this is all just an example of what I eventually want to insert
            <paper-checkbox for></paper-checkbox>
            <div vertical layout>
                <h4>MakeCircuitCreated</h4>
            </div>
        </core-label> // end of example of insert
    </core-header-panel>
</paper-shadow>
```

and JQuery:

```
function addHeaders(){
    $.getJSON('http://myURL/getDataHeaders', function(data) {
        var headerArray = [];
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $('#graphHeaderList').append("<div id='" +val +"'></div>");
                console.log(val);
                headerArray.push(val)
            });
            console.log(headerArray);
        });
    }
        window.onload = addHeaders; //grabs the header values when the page is loaded
```

My JSON:

```
{
"headers": [
    "MakeSpawnFish",
    "MakeEndGame",
    "MakeModeChange",
    "MakeConnectComponent",
    "MakeCircuitCreated",
    "MakeStartGame",
    "MakeSnapshot",
    "MakeResetBoard",
    "MakeAddComponent",
    "MakeCaptureFish",
    "MakeRemoveComponent",
    "MakeDisconnectComponent"
]
}
```

Comment: What are the error messages you're getting ?

Comment: No error messages but nothing is appending

Comment: Basically nothing shows up in the generated html

Comment: are you trying to do this with jquery or with polymer? i don't think the two work very well with each other. and i honestly don't see the need for jquery if using polymer.  i recommend core-ajax and and a repeat template https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-ajax

Comment: Hey Jimi - seems like every time I'm having an issue lately you come to my aid ;)

I tend to agree with you about this as I was able to use a non-polymer <div> and it worked fine. I'm going to try with core-ajax, as the demo seems to do what I need but you might see another question about it later

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me your $.each is calling the wrong thing.

In your json file you have a key called `headers`. When your each function iterates, it gets 1 key and adds it's members, which is an array, to the div. I tested it and got one div with every single member as it's id!

So you may need to nest a second each function to be called on the inner array

```js
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(index,value){
        $('#graphHeaderList').append("<div id=" + "'" + value + "'"  + "></div>");
          console.log(value);
          headerArray.push(value);
    }
);
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: This definitely gets me closer - but still nothing is showing up in the html. Can't figure out why the .append doesn't seem to append to #graphHeaderList

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
$('#graphHeaderList').append("<div id='" +val +"'></div>");
```

Won't work, because jQuery can't find the element in its scope. However, polymer automatically creates id element references through its [automatic node finding](http://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) feature:

```
this.$.graphHeaderList
```

So it should work as expected if you use:

```
$(this.$.graphHeaderList).append("<div id='" +val +"'></div>");
```